# I want to display numbers on the system tray notification Icons on windows

Tags: windows, notifications, icons, system, system-tray

I am trying to create a notification Icon based application in which I want to display some numbers ranging from 1-999.

I looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZeTCcP-qmA&ab_channel=techhead287) which is similar to what I want to do but here the system tray icon just displays the icon and it shows a pop up rather than the system tray icon showing the number or any text.

Excluding the popup item, all I want to do is to read a number (input from somewhere) and display that number in the notification icon section.

I am open to trying any technology (QT, .net) for doing this.  Basically, I am looking for some examples.

Comment: Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While parts of your question are vague, this is very possible, I'd even dare-say quite simple.  Since you mentioned you're open to trying any technology, C# would probably simplify things for you.

- Generate a new 16 x 16 `Bitmap` and draw the number to it using the `Graphics` class.
- Convert the `Image` instance to an `Icon` instance, after disposing of your `Graphics` object.
- Set the `Icon` property of your `NotifyIcon` to the icon you've just created.

These are the basic steps.  You'll likely need to do some research if you aren't familiar with the classes used.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for replying to my question.  Here is what I came up with.  Not sure if this is what you were talking about.

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Resources._16by16BitmapIcon);
            RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(2, 2, 16, 16);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
             g.DrawString("99", new Font("Tahoma", 7), Brushes.Blue, rectf);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            pictureBox1.Height = bmp.Height;
            pictureBox1.Width = bmp.Width;
            g.Dispose();
            var thumb = (Bitmap)bmp.GetThumbnailImage(64, 64, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            thumb.MakeTransparent();
            notifyIcon1.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(thumb.GetHicon());

Now my next question could this be done in a better way?  This is my first C Sharp app so any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Your code looks fine, but you shouldn't post answers to your question unless they actually are answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ShowText(string text, Font font, Color col)
{
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(col);

    // Create a bitmap and draw text on it
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(16, 16);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, 0, 0);

    // Convert the bitmap with text to an Icon
    Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());

    m_notifyIcon.Icon = icon;
}
```